# Dynamic navigation for a gallery page

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create dynamic categories nav for a gallery page.

The structure of the nav would be:

```
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Category1</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">SubCategory1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">SubCategory2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">SubCategory3</a></li>
                </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Category2</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">SubCategory1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">SubCategory2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">SubCategory3</a></li>
                </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

The current tables I created in my database are:

categories

idCat

Category

subcategories

idSub

subCategory

cat_sub

idCat

idSub

And what I have so far in PHP and MySQL statements is:

```
            <?php
                $con = mysql_connect("localhost", "xray", "password") or die('Could not connect to server');
                mysql_select_db("xray", $con) or die('Sorry, could not connect to the database');

                $query = "SELECT categories.Category, categories.idCat, subcategories.subCategory, subcategories.idSub 
                FROM categories JOIN cat_sub ON categories.idCat = cat_sub.idCat
                JOIN subcategories ON subcategories.idSub = cat_sub.idSub";

                $result = mysql_query($query) or die('Error');

                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){

                }
            ?>
```

I think I am probably using the wrong join, as its returning each Category several times.
And I am not sure how to structure the while loop to achieve the above mentioned structure. Any advice would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Aleks

Comment: What do you want it to return? It's ok that it returns each category more than once, once for each subcategory is what I'd expect

Comment: So what I want it to return is first the category, followed by its subcategories. Ex. category - year, followed by subcategories 2013, 2012, 2011. Ultimately I want the structure to be in a list format as shown above.

Comment: No. You return the categories as many times as there are sub-categories. Then you use a loop to format that result as above. In pseudo code it's `while category = $category do this else do that`. In other words, your query is fine.

Comment: Hi Strawberry. Good to know I am on the right path with the query. Thanks for the help. But still not sure how to build the structure in the while statement. Could you expand on the while category = $category part?